# Why does rank 14 output at the end of the first if statement even though it says if(rank == 0)?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, knapsack-problem

I am trying to use MPI to develop a parallel solution in C to the NP-Complete Knapsack problem. When I run the code, the printf statement at the end of the first if statement outputs as rank 14, not rank 0, but it is in an if statement requiring it to be rank 0. Why is this occurring? Is there a way for me to resolve this issue?

```
//Parallel Code using MPI of the NP-Complete Knapsack problem

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <time.h>

int max(int a, int b) {
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Initialize MPI
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int numprocs, rank;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Status status;

    // Declare variables
    double start_time, end_time;
    int n = 3; // number of items
    int W = 10; // knapsack capacity
    int weights[] = {4, 7, 3};// weight of each item
    int profits[] = {4, 5, 7}; // profit of each item

    int weightsbfr[] = {}; // weight buffer
    int profitsbfr[] = {}; // profit buffer

    int chunk_size = 0; // number of items to be processed by each process

    // Calculate chunk size
    chunk_size = n / numprocs;
    if (chunk_size * numprocs < n) {
        chunk_size++; // add 1 to chunk_size to account for the remainder
    }

    // best solution found so far
    int best_weights[] = {}; // weight of the best solution found so far
    int best_profits[] = {}; // profit of the best solution found so far

    int local_final_weight = 0; // weight of the local solution of the current process
    int local_final_profit = 0; // profit of the local solution of the current process

    //final summed values for profit and weight
    int global_final_profit = 0;
    int global_final_weight = 0;

    //Local variables
    int local_weights[] = {}; // local solution of the current process
    int local_profits[] = {}; // profit of the local solution of the current process

    weightsbfr = (int*) malloc(chunk_size * sizeof(int));
    profitsbfr = (int*) malloc(chunk_size * sizeof(int));


    if (rank == 0) {
        printf("Rank: %d\n", rank);
        start_time = MPI_Wtime();
        // send weights and profits to all processes
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i < numprocs; i++) {
            //Split up weights and profits into chunks for each process
            int j;
            for (j = 1; j < chunk_size; j++) { 
                weightsbfr[j] = weights[i * chunk_size + j]; //split weights
                profitsbfr[j] = profits[i * chunk_size + j]; //split profits
            }

            MPI_Send(weightsbfr, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); //send weights
            MPI_Send(profitsbfr, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); //send profits
        }
        //Copy weights and profits into local variables
        int g;
        for (g = 0; g < chunk_size; g++) {
            local_weights[g] = weights[g];
            local_profits[g] = profits[g];
        }
        //Calculate local solution
        int w;
        int K[n + 1][W + 1];

        // Build table K[][] in bottom up manner
        for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            for (w = 0; w <= W; w++) {
                if (i == 0 || w == 0)
                    K[i][w] = 0;
                else if (weights[i - 1] <= w)
                    K[i][w] = max(profits[i - 1] + K[i - 1][w - weights[i - 1]], K[i - 1][w]);
                else
                    K[i][w] = K[i - 1][w];
            }
        }
        //Copy local solution into local variables
        int k;
        for (k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
            for (w = 0; w <= W; w++) {
                local_weights[k] = K[k][w];
                local_profits[k] = K[k][w];
            }
        }
        //Copy local solution into global variables
        global_final_weight = 0;
        global_final_profit = 0;
        for (k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
            best_weights[k] = local_weights[k];
            best_profits[k] = local_profits[k];
            //add up weight and profit of local solution
            global_final_weight += local_weights[k];
            global_final_profit += local_profits[k];
        }
        printf("Initial solution: %d, %d\n", global_final_weight, global_final_profit);
        //print best_weights and best_profits
        printf("Best weights: [");
        for (k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
            printf("%d ", best_weights[k]);
        }
        printf("]\n");
        printf("Rank at end of first if statement: %d\n", rank);
    }
    else {
        MPI_Recv(weightsbfr, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE); //receive weights
        MPI_Recv(profitsbfr, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE); //receive profits
        //Copy weights and profits into local variables
        int h;
        for (h = 0; h < chunk_size; h++) {
            local_weights[h] = weightsbfr[h];
            local_profits[h] = profitsbfr[h];
        }
        //Calculate local solution
        int z, w;
        int K[n + 1][W + 1];
        for (z = 0; z <= n; z++) { //for each item
            for (w = 0; w <= W; w++) { //for each weight
                if (z == 0 || w == 0) //if no items or no weight
                    K[z][w] = 0; //set value to 0
                else if (local_weights[z - 1] <= w) //if weight of item is less than or equal to current weight
                    K[z][w] = max(local_profits[z - 1] + K[z - 1][w - local_weights[z - 1]], K[z - 1][w]); //set value to max of profit of item + value of item at (i-1, w-weight of item) and value of item at (i-1, w)
                else
                    K[z][w] = K[z - 1][w]; //set value to value of item at (i-1, w)
            }
        }
        //Copy local solution into local variables
        int k;
        for (k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
            for (w = 0; w <= W; w++) {
                local_weights[k] = K[k][w]; //this might be an issue copying a 2D array into a 1D array
                local_profits[k] = K[k][w];
            }
        }
        //calculate local final profit and weight
        //sum contents of local_weights and local_profits
        local_final_profit = 0;
        local_final_weight = 0;
        for (h = 0; h < n; h++) {
            local_final_profit += local_profits[h];
            local_final_weight += local_weights[h];
        }

        //Send local solution to process 0
        MPI_Send(local_weights, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); //send weights
        MPI_Send(local_profits, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); //send profits
        MPI_Send(&local_final_weight, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); //send final weight
        MPI_Send(&local_final_profit, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); //send final profit
        printf("Process %d sent solution to process 0.\n", rank);
    }
    printf("Rank: %d\n", rank);
    if (rank == 0) {
        printf("inside loop");
        int x;
        printf("numprocs: %d\n", numprocs);
        for(x = 1; x < numprocs; x++) {
            printf("Receiving solution from process %d...\n", x);
            MPI_Recv(local_weights, 1, MPI_INT, x, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); //receive weights
            MPI_Recv(local_profits, 1, MPI_INT, x, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); //receive profits
            MPI_Recv(&local_final_weight, 1, MPI_INT, x, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); //receive final weight
            MPI_Recv(&local_final_profit, 1, MPI_INT, x, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); //receive final profit
            //Compare local solution to best solution
            if (local_final_profit > global_final_profit) {
                printf("New best solution found!\n");
                printf("New best profit total: %d\n", local_final_profit);
                printf("New best weight total: %d\n", local_final_weight);
                printf("Previous best profit total: %d\n", global_final_profit);
                printf("Previous best weight total: %d\n", global_final_weight);
                int l;
                for (l = 0; l <= n; l++) { //for each item
                    best_weights[l] = local_weights[l];
                    best_profits[l] = local_profits[l];
                }
            }
        }
        end_time = MPI_Wtime();
        printf("Time taken: %f\n", end_time - start_time);
        printf("Best profit total: %d\n", global_final_profit);
        printf("Best weight total: %d\n", global_final_weight);
        //Print arrays of best weights and profits

        //printf("Item weights: %d\n", &best_weights);
        //printf("Item values: %d\n", &best_profits);
    }
    /*
    free(weights);
    free(profits);
    free(weightsbfr);
    free(profitsbfr);
    free(best_weights);
    free(best_profits);
    free(local_weights);
    free(local_profits);
    */
    printf("Process %d finished.\n", rank);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I expect that rank 0 performs the rank 0 designated code without switching into a different rank. See the output here when I run using mpirun -np 1 code:[Output when running with 1 processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEuNS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tracked the variable in Memory?  I suspect the variable is being overwritten in one of the Loops.

Take a closer look at these:

```
// best solution found so far
int best_weights[] = {}; 
int best_profits[] = {}; 

//Local variables
int local_weights[] = {}; 
int local_profits[] = {};
```

I think these are leading to an overwrite of the Rank variable...